# Displaying String based on 3 int values

Tags: ios, swift, string, string-formatting

I'm trying to display a string in this format

```
x day, y hr, z min
```

where x, y, z are Int values from user and user is required to send in at least 5 min if day and hr are 0.

This is my function where I handle displaying user input

```
    func pickerTimeShow(day: Int, hour: Int, minutes: Int) -> String {
    if day > 0 {
        return "\(day) day, \(hour) hr, \(minutes) min"
    }
    if hour > 0 {
        return "\(hour) hr, \(minutes) min"
    }
    return "\(minutes) min"
}
```

However, if user sends pickerTimeShow(day: 0, hour: 2, minutes: 0), my string will show

```
2 hr, 0 min
```

which is not idea because it supposes to just show

```
2 hr
```

In addition, if user sends pickerTimeShow(day: 5, hour: 0, minutes: 5), my string will show

```
5 day, 0 hr, 5 min
```

but I just want

```
5 day, 5 min
```

Do you have a simple solution to handle this case? I really can't think of anything else besides adding more if statement to check which makes my function really long. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.  Put the pieces into an array and then join them at the end:

```
func pickerTimeShow(day: Int, hour: Int, minutes: Int) -> String {
    var result = [String]()

    if day > 0 {
        result.append("\(day) day")
    }

    if hour > 0 {
        result.append("\(hour) hr")
    }

    if minutes > 0 {
        result.append("\(minutes) min")
    }

    if result.isEmpty {
        // decide what to return in the case that all are zero
        return "0 min"
    } else {
        return result.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}
```

---

**Tests:**

```
pickerTimeShow(day: 0, hour: 0, minutes: 0)  // "0 min"
pickerTimeShow(day: 5, hour: 0, minutes: 0)  // "5 day"
pickerTimeShow(day: 0, hour: 6, minutes: 0)  // "6 hr"
pickerTimeShow(day: 0, hour: 0, minutes: 7)  // "7 min"
pickerTimeShow(day: 5, hour: 6, minutes: 0)  // "5 day, 6 hr"
pickerTimeShow(day: 0, hour: 6, minutes: 7)  // "6 hr, 7 min"
pickerTimeShow(day: 5, hour: 0, minutes: 7)  // "5 day, 7 min"
pickerTimeShow(day: 5, hour: 6, minutes: 7)  // "5 day, 6 hr, 7 min"
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively – if you can live with `5 days` rather than `5 day` – this is a solution using `DateComponentsFormatter`

```
func pickerTimeShow(day: Int, hour: Int, minutes: Int) -> String? {
    let dateComponents = DateComponents(day: day, hour: hour, minute: minutes)
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .short
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute]
    return formatter.string(from: dateComponents)
}
```

The function returns `nil` if the input is *out-of-order*.

Comment: Great suggestion! (Voted) However, it looks like the unitsStyle should be `.full`. `.short` seems to give abbreviations.

Comment: (And the DateComponentsFormatter uses singular/plural unit name appropriately, which seems like an improvement over the OPs desired output.